# Count number of cells that match criteria with nested IF and COUNTIF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use an excel formula to count the number of cells in a given range (let's say T132:T134) that match a specific line of text, however cells should only be counted if in a different range (say F132:F134) the corresponding cell in the same row is different from a specific line of text. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
=IF(T132:T134<>"Not applied";COUNTIF(F132:F134;"*WN(1)*"))
```

which should count the number of cells in the range F132:F134 that are equal to "*WN(1)*" only if the corresponding cell in the range T132:T134 is different from "Not applied". However this does not work, but if I apply the same expression to specific cells it works without any problem, as follows:

```
=IF(T134<>"Not applied";COUNTIF(F134;"*WN(1)*"))
```

Is there any way to apply this principle to a range of cells, such as the one in the example that does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didnt you meant to use `COUNTIFS`?:

```
=COUNTIFS(T132:T134,"<>Not applied",F132:F134,"WN(1)")
```

Using wildcards like `*` makes for matches that are not necessarily equal. If you did meant to search within a cells content you can apply the wildcard again like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(T132:T134,"<>Not applied",F132:F134,"*WN(1)*")
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an OR inside the COUNTIFS to check if the cell is different from "Not applied" or from another condition?

Comment: It's exactly what this countifs does